# How can I know that my Galaxy's camera and microphone is not being accessed without my knowledge?

Tags: security

A few months back I installed a few apps straight from the internet. One was an ability to run Ruby scripts on my phone, the other was Grooveshark. Both times, an Jellybean 4.2 flagged up a warning saying these programs have the potential to access my camera and microphone, but I ignored them.

Now I'm getting a bit paranoid. With the macbok pro, when the camera is accessed, a little green LED lights up. It's 'hard-wired', as even security programs (for when your macbook's stolen) can't take a photo without the LED lighting up. Luckily, the LED is brighter than your average laptop-theif, and it only lights up for a second, so no problem there.

But with an android you literally have no clue. I tested out the security program Cerberus, and it took videos of audio samples using my Galaxy without the phone giving a hint what was happening.

I've deleted Grooveshark (it's an abysmal app anyway), but I'm still worried about some other program from months ago recording me.

Comment: What was this app that you installed? If it's from a reputable source, then you can be sure it's not recording you after you've uninstalled it.

Comment: You can also check the permissions of the apps that you have installed to see if they even have access to the camera and microphone to begin with. Also, before you get paranoid, check the processes to see if your camera has in fact been running more than usual without you knowing.

Comment: Also check if the app has Internet permission.